# Problem with .release behavior in file_operations

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I'm dealing with a problem in a kernel module that get data from userspace using a /proc entry.

I set open/write/release entries for my own defined /proc entry, and manage well to use it to get data from userspace.
I handle errors in open/write functions well, and they are visible to user as open/fopen or write/fwrite/fprintf errors.

But some of the errors can only be checked at close (because it's the time all the data is available). In these cases I return something different than 0, which I supposed to be in some way the value 'close' or 'fclose' will return to user.

But whatever the value I return my close behave like if all is fine.
To be sure I replaced all the release() code by a simple 'return(-1);' and wrote a program that open/write/close the /proc entry, and prints the close return value (and the errno). It always return '0' whatever the value I give.

Behavior is the same with 'fclose', or by using shell mechanism (echo "..." >/proc/my/entry).

Any clue about this strange behavior that is not the one claimed in many tutorials I found?

BTW I'm using RHEL5 kernel (2.6.18, redhat modified), on a 64bit system.

Thanks.

### Regards,

Yannick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `release()` isn't allowed to cause the `close()` to fail.

You could require your userspace programs to call `fsync()` on the file descriptor before `close()`, if they want to find out about all possible errors; then implement your final error checking in the `fsync()` handler.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It confirms what I have seen from other sources. What is curious is that several tutorials found on the net use the returned value as if it is an error code (i.e. by returning -EBUSY or other errorcodes).
I changed my code to handle most of the error cases in the write() function (which propagates errors). I will look at fsync() call for the remaining ones.

Thanks,
--
Yannick